# Right url for custom post type

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

I have custom post type called news2, and its url is land/news2. The archive page url is working well but how can I set my taxonomy page and single page right

```
// Change custom post type permalinks
function news2_links($post_link, $post = 0) {
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'news2cat' );
  if($post->post_type === 'news2') {
      return home_url('news2/' . $terms[0]->slug . '/' . $post->ID . '/');
  }
  else{
      return $post_link;
  }
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'news2_links', 1, 3);

// Get the Post ID from permalink structure base/CT/Post_ID
function news2_rewrites_init($post_link, $post = 0){
  //add_rewrite_rule('news2/.*/([0-9]+)?$', 'index.php?post_type=news2&p=$matches[1]', 'top');
  add_rewrite_rule('news2\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)?\/([0-9]+)?(page\/)?([0-9]+)?\/?$', 'index.php?paged=$matches[4]&post_type=news2&news2cat=$matches[1]&p=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'news2_rewrites_init');
```

Comment: Did you mean you want to redirect to desired template file? Would you mind elaborate your question with examples?

Comment: I want the custom post type url to be land/news2. Its working well for archive page, but it will return 404 for single post and taxonomy pages if I try land/news2/term, or land/news2/single-post-url

Comment: It looks like your rewrite rule have something wrong. One quick tools to help you in finding a right pattern. You may try the plugin [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/), it displays a list of default and additonal rewrite rules and respective mapping to query vars. Don't worry if it look a bit old in version and untested with new one. It just display and do no harm to your system. I resolved a rewrite by reading through the system default rewrite to write and fine tune.